# Unable to update the EntitySet (no insert function)

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-5

I have this tables in my data base:

- Videos(IDVideo, Name...)
- Episodes(IDEpisode, Name...)
- Versions(IDVersion, Name, ....)
- VideosVersions(IDVideo, IDEpisode, IDVersion)

A version can be for a video or for the episode and the relation in both cases is N:N, a video can have many versions and a version can be asigned to many videos or episodes.

In my edmx model has the four tables.

When I try to assign a new version to a video for example I use this code:

```
VideosVersions myVideoVersion = new VideosVersions();
myVideoVersion.IDVideo = paramVideo.IDVideo;
myVideoVersion.IDVersion = paramVersion.IDVersion;

myContext.VideosVersions.Add(myVideosVersions);
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

But I get the following exception:

```
Unable to update the EntitySet 'VideosVersions' because it has a DefiningQuery and no <InsertFunction> element exists in the <ModificationFunctionMapping> element to support the current operation.
```

Why?

Thanks.

EDIT: in my entity in the edmx model the three properites has a key, so if I am not wrong, this means that the PK of the entity is the combination of the three fields, is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mapper probably couldn't figure out which columns should be the primary key of VideosVersions. This means it doesn't know how to insert new records and only provides the query method. Make sure you have the primary key properly defined on the table, then update the mapping.

Comment: in my entity in the edmx model the three properites has a key, so if I am not wrong, this means that the PK of the entity is the combination of the three fields, is correct?

Comment: It should be. But are they set on the database table as well? Otherwise EF tries to infer them and might get confused.